# How to change the variable value on arduino program using java?

Tags: java

I am new to arduino and I want to interface it using java . I want to know is there a way to change the variable or set the variable using the input from java :D Thanks For reading Hope you can answer my question .. Sorry for my english not my first language :D

Comment: Devise and implement your own custom protocol through the (USB-tunneled) serial connection: the Java side would tell the Arduino “set this variable to this value” and the Arduino would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can't straight-up change variables on the Arduino, you can create your own protocol over a serial connection using processing (https://processing.org) on your computer, and a sketch on Arduino.

Use the function

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

on the arduino to initialise a serial connection to your computer, and then in processing use the lines:

```
Serial myPort;    // Initialise a serial object (do this at the start of the program)

// Inside the setup() function:
String portName = Serial.list()[0];    // Get the first portname on the list (this may need to be changed to get the right one)
myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600);
```

to connect from the computer.

Once you have done this, you can use the functions

```
myPort.write();
```

in processing, and

```
val = Serial.read();
```

To recieve data on the arduino.

Source (see here for more info): https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/connecting-arduino-to-processing/all